# How can I hide an empty second in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have several groupings in my report, and based on a formula, sometimes there are no rows displayed for the parent grouping. How can I hide the parent grouping if there are no rows displayed? I have SupressIfBlank set to true but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little rusty, so bear with me....

In the section properties for the group totals, there's a setting for "Suppress", and one of the options is a button that lets you write a formula (in the most recent version I used, this was blue if blank & red if there's a formula written). Click this, it'll take you to the Formula Editor. Write something that counts the rows and returns a Boolean: True for zero rows, False for non-zero.

Comment: I had to use global variables and BeforeReadingRecords to do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this similar question](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.crystal/2006-03/msg00166.html) I found on the Internet, it doesn't seem like CR has this functionality built in. The options presented there are as follows:

1. Restructure the report's queries so that group headers aren't returned if the detail records are missing. As in you push the formulas down into the queries themselves so that the headers are never returned.
2. Count the number of detail records on a per-header basis. So you make a formula for the header's suppress field, and suppress it if the detail count is 0.

Either of those should work with the majority of reports. Don't know the specifics of how to implement them, though.